# maven config pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

How can I tell maven to put certain files into certain folders?

For example, I want to put security.xml into WEB-INF in target folder.
 By default maven ignoring this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) should do the work. You can use it together with [Maven Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/) if you want to parametrize your config files.

Comment: Thanks, Maven Resources Plugin is what I need. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html